# Fluxbox: how to map a key for taking screenshot of selected area?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fluxbox

I want to map the `Ctrl+Alt+4` to take a screenshot of a selected area. Right now I can do that from a terminal using `gnome-screenshot -a`. I have tried putting:

```
Control Mod1 4 :ExecCommand gnome-screenshot -a`
```

in my `~/.fluxbox/keys` but that does not work -- probably because of the space before `-a`.

Is there a way to map those key combination to take a screenshot of a selected area?

Comment: the part of that keybindung after :ExecCommand is correct.

Comment: @akira I tried removing `ExecCommand`, does not help.

Comment: why would you "remove" it? :ExecCommand xyz is correct. it's either the keys in front of it or "gnome-screenshot" is not in the $PATH of fluxbox.

Comment: @akira I put it back. "gnome-screenshot" must be in the path, since I can execute it with `ALT-F2`.

Comment: if you are able to launch it via alt-f2: then you have a double-entry for control-mod1-4.

Comment: @akira here is the grep on keys:

```grep "Mod1 4" .fluxbox/keys```                  


```Control Mod1 4 :ExecCommand gnome-screenshot -a```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are using an old syntax. It's **Exec** instead of **ExecCommand**

This worked for me:

```
Mod4 4 :Exec gnome-screenshot -a
```

Comment: Well, the question was asked 2 years ago.  At that time it was `ExecCommand`.  Still, yeah, toady's (2016) syntax is `Exec`.